# Toronto Condo light fixture 4 cable

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, light

I’m trying to wire my light to the ceiling, but i’m so lost with this 4 wire coming out from the wall..

Do you guys know what colour should be connected with which?

Thanks for the help!

[image: ceiling 4wire]
[image: light fixture 3wire]

Comment: That sounds important.  Like, not the sort of thing someone should play with if they have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have a common situation of a light fixture box being used as a junction box. That's why there is more than one (switch) or two (power and switch) groups of wires.

You have the less common situation of **conduit**. That's actually a good thing, because it *guarantees* that the whites are all neutral. And with all blacks together and with one lonely separate not-black-or-white-or-green-or-bare wire (yellow), you can pretty safely assume:

- Blacks = Always Hot - Do not do anything with them.
- Whites = Neutral - Add your light fixture white wire to the other whites.
- Yellow = Switched Hot - Connect to your light fixture black wire.
- Green = Ground - Connect to your light fixture bare copper wire.

That being said, there is an additional concern that may apply here. "Condo" normally means multi-unit building. While "condo" as opposed to "rental" or "co-op" or certain other terms generally means "you own everything inside your walls", there may still be local rules that do not allow you (as a non-electrician) to do the type of routine work, such as light fixture or receptacle or switch replacements, that are generally allowed in a detached single-family home. The concern is that if you do something wrong and it starts a fire, it is likely to affect other people in the building. So keep that (and your insurance policy) in mind as you contemplate doing the work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Light black to yellow(switched hot), light white to whites(neutral) and light bare to greens(ground).

They use yellow instead of more common red, for switched hot from the switch.